# R Shiny-->Reactive Environment Errors with nested loops

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, nested-loops

All,

I am working on the following code. Takes some inputs from two files (portfolio and blend) and does some sorting/ functions, then runs a monte carlo-esque simulation into a linear program.  I Think everything is set up correctly, but I am getting some reactivity errors that I can't pin down. Any help would be nice.

```
library(shiny)
library(triangle) 
library(lpSolveAPI) 

# External CSV data
start_mat<-matrix(rep("A",150),ncol=15,nrow=10)
    family_vector<-c("A","B","C","C","D",rep("E",5))
    widgetweight_vect<-rep(5,10)
    comp_weight_vector<-rep(4,10)
    widgets_vector<-rep(100,10)
    portfolio<-cbind.data.frame(start_mat,family_vector,widgetweight_vect,comp_weight_vector,widgets_vector)

start_mat<-matrix(rep("A",150)ncol=15,rnow=10)
    family_vector<-c("A","B","C","C","D",rep("E",5))
    widgetweight_vect<-rep(5,10)
    comp_weight_vector<-rep(4,10)
    widgets_vector<-rep(100,10)
    portolfio<-c(start_mat,family_vector,widgetweight_vect,comp_weight_vectorwidgets_vector)




blend<-matrix(rep(.20,25),nrow=5, ncol=5)
colnames(blend)<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
rownames(blend)<-c("a","b","c","d","e")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("numb", "generate "),
  column(3,numericInput("plan", label = h3("plan"), value = 50)),
  column(3,numericInput("recweeks", label = h3("recweeks"), value = 50)),
  column(3,numericInput("targetgen", label = h3("targetgen"), min= .1, max = .2, value = .17)),
  column(3,numericInput("process_min", label = h3("process_min"), value = 5000)),
  column(3,numericInput("process_target_trsp", label = h3("process_target_trsp"), min= .1, max = 1, value = .95)),
  column(3,numericInput("process_max_trsp", label = h3("process_max_trsp"), min= .1, max = 1, value = 1)),
  column(3,numericInput("planning_cycle", label = h3("planning_cycle"), min= 1, max = 7, value = 2)),
  column(3,numericInput("rec_starting_inventory", label = h3("rec_starting_inventory"), min= 1, max = 10, value = 5)),
  column(3,numericInput("process_min_campaign", label = h3("process_min_campaign"), min= 1, max = 2000, value = 50)),
  column(3,numericInput("widgets_target", label = h3("widgets_target"), min= 5000, max = 7000, value = 5000)),
  column(3,numericInput("widgets_variation_perc", label = h3("widgets_variation_perc"), min= .01, max = .2, value = .05)),
  column(3,numericInput("process_recoup_max", label = h3("process_recoup_max"), min= .20, max = .50, value = .4)),
  br(),
  br(),
  plotOutput("Plot")
)

)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  plan<-reactive({input$plan})
  recweeks<-reactive({input$recweeks})
  targetgen<-reactive({input$targetgen})
  process_min<-reactive({input$process_min})
  process_target_trsp<-reactive({input$process_target_trsp})
  process_max_trsp<-reactive({input$process_max_trsp})
  planning_cycle<-reactive({input$planning_cycle})
  rec_starting_inventory<-reactive({input$rec_starting_inventory})
  process_min_campaign<-reactive({input$process_min_campaign})
  widgets_target<-reactive({input$widgets_target})
  widgets_variation_perc<-reactive({input$widgets_variation_perc})
  process_recoup_max<-reactive({input$process_recoup_max})


  model<- eventReactive(input$numb, {

    totalsim<-as.numeric(plan()*recweeks())

    blend_length<-length(blend)

    nrow<-function(x) dim(x)[1]

    globalinventory<-vector(mode="numeric", length=(length(blend)-1))
    dims<-nrow(portfolio)

    rec_stats<-matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0),ncol=7,nrow=1)
    inventory_byBL<-matrix(c(rep(0,length(blend)-1)),ncol=(length(blend)-1),nrow=1)

    #Set the random number seed
    set.seed(100)

    #Develop table of process performances
    proc_location<-0.0
    proc_myscale<-85.16507
    proc_myshape<-13.35404

    process_trs<-matrix((rweibull(totalsim, shape=proc_myshape, scale=proc_myscale)+proc_location)/100, nrow=totalsim, ncol=1)
    process_trs<-replace(process_trs,process_trs>process_max_trsp(),process_max_trsp())
    process_perf<-process_trs/process_target_trsp()
    process_index<-1
    #write.csv(process_perf,file="MEZprocess_perf.csv")

    #Develop tables of proced rec generations
    location<-5.5646+4
    myscale<-8.07516
    myshape<-3.76987

    recgen_perc<-matrix((rweibull(totalsim*dims, shape=myshape, scale=myscale)+location)/100, nrow=dims, ncol=totalsim)

    #Develop the tables of plan Variations
    trimin<-0.1
    trimax<-2.2
    trimode<-.95
    tri<-rtriangle(totalsim*dims, a=trimin,b=trimax,c=trimode)
    trimat<-matrix(tri,nrow=dims,ncol=totalsim)

    #uniform distribution for some additional variation
    unif_range<-as.numeric(widgets_variation_perc())
    do_var<-matrix(runif(totalsim,min=(1-unif_range),max=(1+unif_range)),nrow=totalsim,ncol=1)

    #Create the rec generation vector

    widgetweight<-portfolio[,17]
    comp_weight<-portfolio[,18]
    family<-as.factor(portfolio[,16])
    widgets<-portfolio[,19]

    for(iii in 1:plan){
      local({
        widgets_base<-widgets*trimat[,iii]
        total_widgets<-sum(widgets_base)
        widgets_base<-widgets_base*widgets_target/total_widgets

        for (ii in 1:recweeks){  ##Iterates through different rec generations
          local({
            widgets_var<-widgets_base*do_var[process_index]

            recgen_gr<-widgetweight*(recgen_perc[,ii])*widgets_var
            parentBL_gr<-comp_weight*(1+targetgen)*widgets_base*process_perf[process_index]
            newportfolio<-data.frame(family,recgen_gr,parentBL_gr)

            #Now create the table of the aggregate values by family for the rec generated and the parent proc available for consumption
            rectable<-aggregate(. ~ newportfolio$family, newportfolio, sum)
            rectable
            rectable<-rectable[,-2]
            colnames(rectable)<-c("Family","recgen_gr","parentBL_gr")
            rectable$parentBL_name<-substr(rectable$Family,1,5)
            rectable

            #Combine the rec generation information with the blend tables. This will be used to generated the constraints for the LP
            #The two constraints that must be generated are the rec generation and the parent proc quantity

            combinedtable<-merge(rectable,blend,all = TRUE)
            combinedtable[is.na(combinedtable)] <- 0
            combinedtable
            parent.table<-data.frame(combinedtable$parentBL_name,combinedtable$parentBL_gr)
            parent.table
            colnames(parent.table)<-c("parentBL_name","parentBL_gr")
            #rec generation constraint created for later use in the LP
            generation.constraint<-combinedtable$recgen_gr

            #Now parent proc constraint 
            blend_parent<-colnames(combinedtable)
            blend_parent<-unlist(colnames(combinedtable[5:ncol(combinedtable)]))
            blend_parent<-data.frame(blend_parent)
            dim(blend_parent)
            colnames(blend_parent)<-("parentBL_name")
            parent_gen<-merge(blend_parent,parent.table)
            parent_gen$gen<-as.factor(match(parent_gen$parentBL_name,blend_parent$parentBL_name))
            parent_gen<-parent_gen[order(parent_gen$gen),]
            parent.constraint<-parent_gen[,2]

            rnd <- function(x) trunc(x+sign(x)*0.5+.5)

            #Create the production wheel based on the minimum run requirement for Z
            parent.wheel<-parent.constraint
            v<-length(parent.wheel)
            parent.wheel<-ifelse(parent.wheel/process_min_campaign>1,1,rnd(process_min_campaign/parent.wheel))
            parent.wheel.adj<-ifelse(process_index%%parent.wheel==0,parent.wheel,0)

            #Now multiple the results of the production wheel to the parent proc constraint to make the proces available to parent proced rec
            parent.constraint_adj<-parent.constraint*parent.wheel.adj

            ##################################################################################################################################################################
            #Create LP with decision variables based on the number of constraints
            n<-length(generation.constraint)

            #Add a factor for "overage" dummy proc if there is rec that cannot be consumed
            m<-length(parent.constraint_adj)+1

            model<-make.lp(0,n*m)

            rhs.gen<-generation.constraint+globalinventory+ifelse(process_index==1,generation.constraint*rec_starting_inventory,0)

            rhs.proc<-parent.constraint_adj

            blend_con<-cbind(1/blend[,2:(length(blend))],over=1000)
            rownames(blend_con)<-blend[,1]
            ####Row Constraints###########################

            add.constraint(model,rep(1,m), "=", rhs.gen[1],indices=c(1:m))
            for (i in 1:(n-1)){
              start<-i*m+1
              end<-i*m+m
              add.constraint(model,rep(1,m), "=", rhs.gen[i+1],indices=c(start:end))
            }

            for (i in 1:n) {
              col<-c()
              for (ii in seq(i,n*m,m)){
                col<-cbind(col,ii)
              }
              col
              add.constraint(model,blend_con[,i],"<=",rhs.proc[i],indices=c(col))
            }

            lp.control(model,sense='max')

            objective<-1:(n*m)
            remove<-seq(m,(n*m),m)

            objective<-objective[-remove]
            length(objective)
            set.objfn(model,rep(1,length(objective)),indices=(objective))
            solve(model)

            write.lp(model,filename="rec_linearprogram.lp")

            get.objective(model)
            length(get.variables(model))
            table<-get.variables(model)
            tablemat<-t(matrix(table,ncol=n,nrow=m))

            sum(rhs.gen)
            get.primal.solution(model, orig = FALSE)
            #get.variables(model)
            values<-get.variables(model)
            values<-values[-objective]
            sum(values)+get.objective(model)
            #print(model)


            #Actual consumption based on rules 
            tablemat_con<- ifelse(tablemat[,1:(m-1)]<process_min,0,tablemat[,1:(m-1)])
            real_consumption<-sum(tablemat_con)                                                         ##Write this value to a table "rec consumed"

            #Remainders that Cannot be consumed because of run rule
            table_mat_remainder<-ifelse(tablemat[,1:(m-1)]<process_min,tablemat[,1:(m-1)],0)
            table_mat_remainder<-rowSums(table_mat_remainder)
            #table_mat_remainder                                                                            ##Write this value to a table "Lost Opportunity"
            missed_op<-sum(table_mat_remainder)
            overage_next_day<-tablemat[,m]
            globalinventory<-overage_next_day+ table_mat_remainder                                          ##Write this value to a table "New Inventory"
            globalinventory_sum<-sum(globalinventory)
            real_con_perc<-real_consumption/(sum(parent_gen[,2])*do_var[process_index])                                             ##achieved rec consumptions
            max_con_perc<-(real_consumption+missed_op)/(sum(parent_gen[,2])*do_var[process_index])                                      ##Unconstrained rec consumption
            actual_gen_perc<-sum(recgen_gr)/(sum(parent_gen[,2])*do_var[process_index])
            colnames(rec_stats)<-c("RealCon","GlobalInven","RealConPer","MaxPotent","ActrecGen","process Performance","tires per day")
            rec_stats<<-rbind(rec_stats,c(real_consumption,globalinventory_sum,real_con_perc,max_con_perc,actual_gen_perc,process_perf[process_index],sum(widgets_var)))
            inventory_byBL<<-rbind(inventory_byBL,c(globalinventory))
            process_index<-process_index+1
          })
        }


        #Plot 1
        plot1<- matplot(rec_stats[,3:5]*100,col=c("springgreen4","grey50","red"),lwd=.5,lty=3,type = c("b"),pch=1,main="Evolution of rec Consumption/Generation",ylab="%", xlab="Days",ylim=c(0,30))

        list(plot1=plot1)
      })
    }
  })
  output$Plot<-renderPlot({model()$plot1})
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Errors:
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):
    48: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
    47: .dependents$register
    46: plan
    45: server [#14]
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: print
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

PS I know I could do a lot of this coding better with plyr and some apply vs loops, but it's what I have.

Comment: When are you getting this error? I took your code and was able to launch the app, but I get a different error when click on "Generate".

Comment: Closed the session and re-ran the script and got a new error message ofWarning: Error in :: NA/NaN argument
Stack trace (innermost first):
    123: eventReactiveHandler [#69]
    103: model
    102: renderPlot [#214]
     92: <reactive:plotObj>
     81: plotObj
     80: origRenderFunc
     79: output$Plot
      4: <Anonymous>
      3: do.call
      2: print.shiny.appobj
      1: print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were miscellaneous errors. There were a few off-by one errors, and a few reactive functions that were missing the `()` (like `plan` needed to be `plan()`).

A few things to point out here:

- In general you should not develop large programs like this in shiny, you should develop them standalone and then put them in a package as functions, preferably with test cases so if you change things you can be assured they still work. This is how the professionals do it.
- When you do need to debug, you can use print statements to figure out where it is failing, and then use the debugger (perhaps by embedding a `browser()` statement) and then stopping and inspecting the variables there.
- If you give R a function name (like you did with `plan`) where it needs a numerical value, it will probably give you a rather confusing error message - like the one you got. So if you see confusing error message, look around for missing brackets like these `()`.
- There are a lot (too many) predefined functions in R with simple names. So if you forget to define or initialize a variable before you use it, R will surprisingly often substitute a function you are not even aware of for it. Like `df` or `sum`. Type in `sum = sum+1` for example and try and make sense of the message.

I had to comment out a constraint block, and change a few off-by-one mismatches to get this to work. It probably will be easy for you to fix these though.

Anyway here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(triangle)
library(lpSolveAPI)

# External CSV data
start_mat <- matrix(rep("A",150),ncol = 15,nrow = 10)
family_vector <- c("A","B","C","C","D",rep("E",5))
widgetweight_vect <- rep(5,10)
comp_weight_vector <- rep(4,10)
widgets_vector <- rep(100,10)
portfolio <- cbind.data.frame(start_mat,family_vector,widgetweight_vect,comp_weight_vector,widgets_vector)

start_mat <- matrix(rep("A",150),ncol = 15,nrow = 10)
family_vector <- c("A","B","C","C","D",rep("E",5))
widgetweight_vect <- rep(5,10)
comp_weight_vector <- rep(4,10)
widgets_vector <- rep(100,10)
portolfio <- c(start_mat,family_vector,widgetweight_vect,comp_weight_vector,widgets_vector)




blend <- matrix(rep(.20,25),nrow = 5,ncol = 5)
colnames(blend) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
rownames(blend) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("numb","generate "),
  column(3,numericInput("plan",label = h3("plan"),value = 50)),
  column(3,numericInput("recweeks",label = h3("recweeks"),value = 50)),
  column(3,numericInput("targetgen",label = h3("targetgen"),min = .1,max = .2,value = .17)),
  column(3,numericInput("process_min",label = h3("process_min"),value = 5000)),
  column(3,numericInput("process_target_trsp",label = h3("process_target_trsp"),min = .1,max = 1,value = .95)),
  column(3,numericInput("process_max_trsp",label = h3("process_max_trsp"),min = .1,max = 1,value = 1)),
  column(3,numericInput("planning_cycle",label = h3("planning_cycle"),min = 1,max = 7,value = 2)),
  column(3,numericInput("rec_starting_inventory",label = h3("rec_starting_inventory"),min = 1,max = 10,value = 5)),
  column(3,numericInput("process_min_campaign",label = h3("process_min_campaign"),min = 1,max = 2000,value = 50)),
  column(3,numericInput("widgets_target",label = h3("widgets_target"),min = 5000,max = 7000,value = 5000)),
  column(3,numericInput("widgets_variation_perc",label = h3("widgets_variation_perc"),min = .01,max = .2,value = .05)),
  column(3,numericInput("process_recoup_max",label = h3("process_recoup_max"),min = .20,max = .50,value = .4)),
  br(),
  br(),
  plotOutput("Plot")
)

)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output) {
  plan <- reactive({ input$plan })
  recweeks <- reactive({ input$recweeks })
  targetgen <- reactive({ input$targetgen })
  process_min <- reactive({ input$process_min })
  process_target_trsp <- reactive({ input$process_target_trsp })
  process_max_trsp <- reactive({ input$process_max_trsp })
  planning_cycle <- reactive({ input$planning_cycle })
  rec_starting_inventory <- reactive({ input$rec_starting_inventory })
  process_min_campaign <- reactive({ input$process_min_campaign })
  widgets_target <- reactive({ input$widgets_target })
  widgets_variation_perc <- reactive({ input$widgets_variation_perc })
  process_recoup_max <- reactive({ input$process_recoup_max })


  model <- eventReactive(input$numb,{

    totalsim <- as.numeric(plan() * recweeks())

    blend_length <- length(blend)
    nrow <- function(x) dim(x)[1]

    globalinventory <- vector(mode = "numeric",length = (length(blend))) # -1 ?
    dims <- nrow(portfolio)

    rec_stats <- matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0),ncol = 7,nrow = 1)
    inventory_byBL <- matrix(c(rep(0,length(blend) - 0)),ncol = (length(blend) - 0 ),nrow = 1) # changed 1 to 0 twice

    #Set the random number seed
    set.seed(100)

    #Develop table of process performances
    proc_location <- 0.0
    proc_myscale <- 85.16507
    proc_myshape <- 13.35404

    process_trs <- matrix((rweibull(totalsim,shape = proc_myshape,scale = proc_myscale) + proc_location) / 100,nrow = totalsim,ncol = 1)
    process_trs <- replace(process_trs,process_trs > process_max_trsp(),process_max_trsp())
    process_perf <- process_trs / process_target_trsp()
    process_index <- 1
    #write.csv(process_perf,file="MEZprocess_perf.csv")

    #Develop tables of proced rec generations
    location <- 5.5646 + 4
    myscale <- 8.07516
    myshape <- 3.76987

    recgen_perc <- matrix((rweibull(totalsim * dims,shape = myshape,scale = myscale) + location) / 100,nrow = dims,ncol = totalsim)

    #Develop the tables of plan Variations
    trimin <- 0.1
    trimax <- 2.2
    trimode <- .95
    tri <- rtriangle(totalsim * dims,a = trimin,b = trimax,c = trimode)
    trimat <- matrix(tri,nrow = dims,ncol = totalsim)

    #uniform distribution for some additional variation
    unif_range <- as.numeric(widgets_variation_perc())
    do_var <- matrix(runif(totalsim,min = (1 - unif_range),max = (1 + unif_range)),nrow = totalsim,ncol = 1)

    #Create the rec generation vector

    widgetweight <- portfolio[,17]
    comp_weight <- portfolio[,18]
    family <- as.factor(portfolio[,16])
    widgets <- portfolio[,19]

    for (iii in 1:plan()) {
      print(sprintf("iii:%d",iii))
      local({
        widgets_base <- widgets * trimat[,iii]
        total_widgets <- sum(widgets_base)
        widgets_base <- widgets_base * widgets_target() / total_widgets

        for (ii in 1:recweeks()) {
          ##Iterates through different rec generations
          # print(sprintf("  ii:%d",ii))
          local( {
            widgets_var <- widgets_base * do_var[process_index]

            recgen_gr <- widgetweight * (recgen_perc[,ii]) * widgets_var
            parentBL_gr <- comp_weight * (1 + targetgen()) * widgets_base * process_perf[process_index]
            newportfolio <- data.frame(family,recgen_gr,parentBL_gr)

            #Now create the table of the aggregate values by family for the rec generated and the parent proc available for consumption
            rectable <- aggregate(. ~ newportfolio$family,newportfolio,sum)
            rectable
            rectable <- rectable[,-2]
            colnames(rectable) <- c("Family","recgen_gr","parentBL_gr")
            rectable$parentBL_name <- substr(rectable$Family,1,5)
            rectable

            #Combine the rec generation information with the blend tables. This will be used to generated the constraints for the LP
            #The two constraints that must be generated are the rec generation and the parent proc quantity

            combinedtable <- merge(rectable,blend,all = TRUE)
            combinedtable[is.na(combinedtable)] <- 0
            combinedtable
            parent.table <- data.frame(combinedtable$parentBL_name,combinedtable$parentBL_gr)
            parent.table
            colnames(parent.table) <- c("parentBL_name","parentBL_gr")
            #rec generation constraint created for later use in the LP
            generation.constraint <- combinedtable$recgen_gr

            #Now parent proc constraint 
            blend_parent <- colnames(combinedtable)
            blend_parent <- unlist(colnames(combinedtable[5:ncol(combinedtable)]))
            blend_parent <- data.frame(blend_parent)
            dim(blend_parent)
            colnames(blend_parent) <- ("parentBL_name")
            parent_gen <- merge(blend_parent,parent.table)
            parent_gen$gen <- as.factor(match(parent_gen$parentBL_name,blend_parent$parentBL_name))
            parent_gen <- parent_gen[order(parent_gen$gen),]
            parent.constraint <- parent_gen[,2]
            rnd <- function(x) trunc(x + sign(x) * 0.5 + .5)

            #Create the production wheel based on the minimum run requirement for Z
            parent.wheel <- parent.constraint
            v <- length(parent.wheel)
            parent.wheel <- ifelse(parent.wheel / process_min_campaign() > 1,1,rnd(process_min_campaign() / parent.wheel))
            parent.wheel.adj <- ifelse(process_index %% parent.wheel == 0,parent.wheel,0)

            #Now multiple the results of the production wheel to the parent proc constraint to make the proces available to parent proced rec
            parent.constraint_adj <- parent.constraint * parent.wheel.adj

            ##################################################################################################################################################################
            #Create LP with decision variables based on the number of constraints
            n <- length(generation.constraint)

            #Add a factor for "overage" dummy proc if there is rec that cannot be consumed
            m <- length(parent.constraint_adj) + 1
            model <- make.lp(0,n * m)

            rhs.gen <- generation.constraint + globalinventory + ifelse(process_index == 1,generation.constraint * rec_starting_inventory(),0)
            rhs.proc <- parent.constraint_adj

            blend_con <- cbind(1 / blend[,2:(dim(blend)[2])],over = 1000)
            rownames(blend_con) <- blend[,1]
            ####Row Constraints###########################
            add.constraint(model,rep(1,m),"=",rhs.gen[1],indices = c(1:m))
            for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
              start <- i * m + 1
              end <- i * m + m
              add.constraint(model,rep(1,m),"=",rhs.gen[i + 1],indices = c(start:end))
            }


            #for (i in 1:n) {
              #col <- c()
              #for (ii in seq(i,n * m,m)) {
                #col <- cbind(col,ii)
              #}
              #col
              #add.constraint(model,blend_con[,i],"<=",rhs.proc[i],indices = c(col))
            #}

            lp.control(model,sense = 'max')

            objective <- 1:(n * m)
            remove <- seq(m,(n * m),m)

            objective <- objective[-remove]
            length(objective)
            set.objfn(model,rep(1,length(objective)),indices = (objective))
            solve(model)

            write.lp(model,filename = "rec_linearprogram.lp")

            get.objective(model)
            length(get.variables(model))
            table <- get.variables(model)
            tablemat <- t(matrix(table,ncol = n,nrow = m))
            sum(rhs.gen)
            get.primal.solution(model,orig = FALSE)
            #get.variables(model)
            values <- get.variables(model)
            values <- values[-objective]
            sum(values) + get.objective(model)
            #print(model)



            #Actual consumption based on rules 
            tablemat_con <- ifelse(tablemat[,1:(m - 1)] < process_min(),0,tablemat[,1:(m - 1)])
            real_consumption <- sum(tablemat_con) ##Write this value to a table "rec consumed"

            #Remainders that Cannot be consumed because of run rule
            table_mat_remainder <- ifelse(tablemat[,1:(m - 1)] < process_min(),tablemat[,1:(m - 1)],0)
            #table_mat_remainder <- rowSums(table_mat_remainder)
            table_mat_remainder <- sum(table_mat_remainder)
            #table_mat_remainder                                                                            ##Write this value to a table "Lost Opportunity"
            missed_op <- sum(table_mat_remainder)
            overage_next_day <- tablemat[,m]
            globalinventory <- overage_next_day + table_mat_remainder ##Write this value to a table "New Inventory"
            globalinventory_sum <- sum(globalinventory)
            real_con_perc <- real_consumption / (sum(parent_gen[,2]) * do_var[process_index]) ##achieved rec consumptions
            max_con_perc <- (real_consumption + missed_op) / (sum(parent_gen[,2]) * do_var[process_index]) ##Unconstrained rec consumption
            actual_gen_perc <- sum(recgen_gr) / (sum(parent_gen[,2]) * do_var[process_index])
            colnames(rec_stats) <- c("RealCon","GlobalInven","RealConPer","MaxPotent","ActrecGen","process Performance","tires per day")
            rec_stats <<- rbind(rec_stats,c(real_consumption,globalinventory_sum,real_con_perc,max_con_perc,actual_gen_perc,process_perf[process_index],sum(widgets_var)))
            inventory_byBL <<- rbind(inventory_byBL,c(globalinventory))
            process_index <- process_index + 1
          })
        }
        #Plot 1
        plot1 <- matplot(rec_stats[,c(1,2,6,7)] * 100,col = c("springgreen4","grey50","red"),lwd = .5,lty = 3,type = c("b"),pch = 1,main = "Evolution of rec Consumption/Generation",ylab = "%",xlab = "Days",ylim = c(0,30))

        list(plot1 = plot1)
      })
    }
  })
  output$Plot <- renderPlot({ model()$plot1 })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

And this is what it outputs:

[image]